# Evaluating A/B test using confidence intervals

Tags: confidence-interval, variance, mean, ab-test

I have a situation where I worked on two different flavors of a website say A and B (using some fictitious numbers for illustration). For A the amount of time spent by users went up by 1% for 1 million users and for B the amount of time spent went up by 1.01% for 1 million users. How can I determine if B is better than A in terms of confidence intervals? I want to be able to say that mean(B - A) = 0.0001 with a high confidence. Would my null hypothesis be: mean (B -A) = 0.0001? I am a little confused as to how to calculate the conf interval. For a 95% conf interval is this correct? :

C = 1.96 * sqrt[(0.01 * 0.99 + 0.0101 * 0.9899)/1000000]

Which comes to 0.000376 but I am confused as to how to interpret it. My true mean will lie in the interval 0.0001 +/- C but it already contains my sample mean so how do I accept or reject my null hypothesis?

EDIT: This is the solution I came up with after reading the comment by Kitter Catter. My null hypothesis is that there is no difference between A and B. Therefore my H0: mean(B-A) = 0. C is as calculated above for a 95% CI which comes to

```
 >>> sigsq = (0.01 * 0.99 + 0.9899 * 0.0101)
 >>> C = 1.96 * np.sqrt(sigsq/1000000)
 >>> mu = 0.0001
 >>> mu - C
-0.00017647806130686029
```

So the 95% confidence interval should contain 0.0 so the null hypothesis is acceptable.

Comment: Your null hypothesis is typically the thing you are trying to disprove or a default assumption. In this case it seems like it would be that mean(B-A) = 0.

Answer (score 0):

Since the distribution of times is often heavily skewed, it makes sense to log-transform these values. This has the added advantage of producing a test for geometric mean difference. A value of 1 and 1.2 have a geometric mean difference of 20% as does 10 and 12, and 100 and 120: the are all 20% higher than the referent value.

If you perform a log transform, you calculate a symmetric CI for the logged times, and calculate a difference from 0. Of course, log-time is not intuitive, so it makes sense to transform the point estimate and 95% CI using exponentiation. The resulting *non*-symmetric 95% CI can be used to test the hypothesis for whether the *ratio* of times spent on the website is different from *1*. If the CI does not include 1, reject the null hypothesis, and say that the geometric mean difference of times on the website was statistically significantly different from 1, or 100%, meaning no difference.

Comment: Thanks but I am not sure I understood this well. So log transformation means to compare the log of the increase in time spent on the website? I am not sure how it helps me to answer the question : was B more effective than A given the 0.01% difference?

Comment: @user3079275 You need to define how you are comparing groups, a difference or a ratio? A difference different from 0 implies a ratio different from 1. You log transform because you are measuring a ratio. If B/A is different from 1, you can reject a null hypothesis of "no effect".

Comment: In my mind I was using a difference (see my edit to the question). My null hypothesis is now mean (B-A) = 0. Is a ratio and log transform a better way to do it?